# What English word does the `b` in `\bbox` represent?

Tags: boxes, documentation, tex-history

Two of the LaTeX commands for building boxes are:

- The `h` in `\hbox` is a subsequence of the English word ***horizontal***
- The `v` in `\vbox` is a subsequence of the English word ***vertical***

What English word might be a super-sequence of the `b` in `\bbox` and have some meaning which is sensible for `\bbox`?

Comment: which package defines \bbox? I would guess bounding box (like bb  key of includegraphics for example) but it depends on the command,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle provided good advice. I would have guessed "bounding box" but that is 2-dimensional, with 4 corners. We do not know where you obtained the `\bbox` macro, but a bounding box does it have 4 possible values, each of which is an X,Y location? Anyway... The reason I commented is because the question invites imaginative answers, such as `banana`.

Comment: BTW: `\hbox` and `\vbox` are (low level) TeX not LaTeX. LaTeX commands would be `\mbox`, `\makebox`, `\parbox` and also the `minipage` environment.